# How can I insert data from one table into another?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am working with Oracle 12c and i have three tables which are related. First table is related to student, second one related to student library information and last is related to to final student library information. These are the table structures:

**Student table**

```
 CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."STUDENT" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "CLASS" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE), 
    "MOBILE" NUMBER(10,0), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))
```

**Student Library Details**

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."STUDENT_LIBRARY_DETAILS" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "Borrower_ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "BOOK_ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "Borrowed_From_Date" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "Borrowed_To_Date" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "Actual_Return_date" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "Issued_by" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))
```

**Student library final information**

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."FINAL_LIBRARY_DETAILS" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "Borrower_ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "TOTAL_BOOK_ISSUED_COUNT" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "isAccountCloseed" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))
```

Data in my tables are :-

[image]

In above image, in student table, student with ID S01 has issued 3 books.

So my problem is that i want to insert data into third table by calculating student library details table; for example if student with ID 
`S01` issues three books then total book count will be 3 with distinct student ID.

Please suggest how can I insert data into third table using logic in Oracle.

Comment: Is your question really how to insert, or hot to count the rows in the first place? And why do you want a third table, which you have to maintain as rows are added/modified/removed from the other two tables; rather than a view? (The student table doesn't seem directly relevant to the third table/view anyway; but where is the account-closed flag supposed to come from?)

Comment: Why do you want to insert value in third table? What's your requirement?

Comment: Pro tip: don't use double-quotes to make your columns case sensitive -  `"Borrowed_From_Date"`. Those names will be a constant pain in the neck to you and anybody else unlucky enough to have to work with your data model. Especially as you're not even consistent with the capitalization: `TOTAL_BOOK_ISSUED_COUNT`, etc

Comment: Due to some structure changes in table2(STUDENT_LIBRARY_DETAILS) so i need third table(FINAL_LIBRARY_DETAILS).